# How to get random 0 and 1 numbers

Tags: ruby, loops, random

So basically for fun I was trying to generate a column of numbers (7 digits only 0s and 1s)
My code's pretty short:

```
a = rand(0000000-1111111)
b = 220
a1 = rand(0000000-1111111)
a2 = rand(0000000-1111111)
a3 = rand(0000000-1111111)
a4 = rand(0000000-1111111)
a5 = rand(0000000-1111111)

while b !=0
  puts a
  puts a2
  puts a3
  puts a4
  puts a5
end
```

My problem is that instead of generating a random column of 0s and 1s *all* the numbers are used.

Comment: Make an empty string. Generate one number at a time, like so rand(0-1), and append it to the string that was empty at first. Do that as many times as you want digits. You cannot treat decimals numbers this way without telling the language in some way or another. I'm sorry I can't do the code for you - I don't have a ruby implementation installed...

Comment: Did you look up how the random function works? And subtraction? And loop termination?

Comment: If you can print binary easily, you can generate number from 0-127 and print the binary form of them.

Comment: @Morten Let me tell you a secret - I actually use the site repl.it ;)

Comment: @Dave Yes, I did I'm not familiar with ALL of them but I can use them

Comment: @nhatdh I do not know how to do that

Comment: Could we have some follow-up? Is it working now? Which method did you use?

Comment: @Tim Here's your follow-up code that I made(mentioned below): `5.times do puts (1..7).map { rand(2) }.join end`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's idiomaticish Ruby:

```
5.times do
  puts (1..7).map { [0, 1].sample }.join
end
```

Let's unpack it:

`5.times do...end` is pretty self-explanatory. Do whatever's between `do` and `end` five times.

`(1..7)` generates an array with seven elements. We don't actually care what's in it right now. `map` returns a new array where each element is the result of calling what's between the braces. So seven times we'll call `[0, 1].sample` and squeeze the results into an array. The `sample` itself, of course, randomly picks either `0` or `1`. Finally `.join` turns an array into a string. If we'd said `.join('-')`, for example, it'd put a hyphen between each element (1-0-0-1-1-1-0-1). But since we didn't specify anything it puts nothing between each element (10011101).

And there you have it.

As others have noted, for this particular problem it's possible to do faster and shorter things by using binary. I don't think this is the Ruby Way though. With respect to speed, "premature optimization is the root of all evil", and if you have a violent aversion to slow code you shouldn't be coding Ruby anyway. With regards to readability, that way may be shorter, but the above way is a lot clearer. "Oh, we're doing something five times, and that's going to be printing out a 7-thing long...random sequence of 0s and 1s...as a string". It almost reads like English (if you know the word [map](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/map#Verb) (definition three)).

Comment: I guess it depends upon the problem statement and the _reason_ for the program to exist at all. When I hear that seven `0` or `1` numbers are to be generated, I can _only_ think of the representations of `0..127`, so it feels the most natural for me. Your clever `(1..7)` avoids the horrible proliferation of variables that would be used in naive code -- and teaches the useful tool of making an anonymous array that is quickly discarded.

Comment: Your version would be much easier to _extend_ to N columns of `a`, `7`, and `€` characters -- but minitech's version feels more natural to me if the problem is closely tied to _number_ representations.

Comment: Here's a modified version of this code that I used (sometimes it generates random ASCII art :D) `code`5.times do
  puts (1..7).map { rand(2) }.join
end`code`

Comment: Strictly speaking, `(1..7)` does not generate an array, as it is a range consisting only of endpoints. It's not until `map` is called on the range that an array is created, which is populated with `map`s transformation of the elements yielded by calling `each` on the range.

Comment: +1, this is a much better solution. (And the binary part isn't for optimization - I just thought this would be longer (which it's not) (but that's partially because I tried another way).)

Comment: That's a good point Andrew, +1. Given the perceived level of the OP it seemed like an acceptable handwave though.

Comment: Good explanation. Rather than `rand(2)` I'd use `[0,1].sample` which I think more clearly shows the intent.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to solve this is probably to do base conversion:

```
someNumber = rand(1 << 7) # Seven digits, max; 1 << 7 is 10000000 in binary.

puts someNumber.to_s(2).ljust(7, '0') # 10110100, e.g.
```

Comment: @DGM: I have *really* big fingers ;)

Comment: as luck would have it, I got an output of "0000"   :D

Comment: Nice use of bit-shift to reduce the magic-numberness of just saying `128`.

Comment: @Linuxios: The OP essentially wants to get a random binary number; and it's not hacky at all for that =)

Comment: @minitech: That doesn't mean I don't like it ;). +1. I like things that involve bits. I'm very impressed that this is what you thought of, not some string-appending loop business.

Answer (score 2):

Derivation of @minitech's answer

```
 5.times { puts "%07b" % rand(128) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby does not understand from your `rand()` inputs that you want specifically-formatted numbers.

Instead generate each digit randomly (`rand(2)`) and build the entire number out of seven variables like this. Print the result on a line of its own then restart the loop.

Another option is to generate a random number between `0` and `127` and then format it for binary output. This spends much less time in the random number generator and drastically reduces the variables in your program.

Either approach is just fine for a learning program. Try both and see which version you prefer. Try to understand why you prefer one way over another.

Comment: could someone tell me how to do option 2?

Comment: [Minitech's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11111899/377270) has that very well covered. :) I didn't expect converting the number to binary to be as simple as `to_s(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that generates an arbitrary number (default 1) of binary numbers of a specified length:

```
def random_binary(length, n=1)
  raise ArgumentError if n < 1
  (1..n).map { "%0#{length}b" % rand(2**length) }
end

random_binary(7, 5)
#=> ["0011100", "1001010", "0101111", "0010101", "1100101"]
```